# Minimum Overlap

Tags: combinatorics, puzzle, combinations

You have a set of ten numbers, and you are trying to cover all 4-element subsets of this set. To do this, you choose 5 elements from the set every time and you cover all 4-element subsets of your choice. What is the minimum number of selections you need to complete all 4-element subsets of the ten number set?

For example if you choose 12345, you cover 1234,1235,1245,1345 and 2345. But as you go on, the overlaps seem to be inevitable. I couldn't figure out the strategy to minimize it.

Comment: There are 210 4-element sets, so you'll need at least 42 5-element sets. Trying to think about whether 42 can actually be achieved: you'd need to find 42 5-element sets such that any pair of them intersect in at most 3 elements. That sounds like a combinatorial design problem, though I couldn't figure out if it's been studied.

Comment: I've been trying to do exactly what you said, but it's really hard to find the answer by trying. I was hoping there was a mathematical solution for this.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't make any progress either. I don't have a good intuition about whether 42 is possible or not.